# SSRS The permissions are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS and deployed my first report with it.  When deploying the report, I added access to the site for the user group DOMAIN\user-group with the "System User' role under Site Settings > Security.  I also added the group to the home folder with the browser role and ensured all folders and items inherit parent settings.  The report is running with a service account with SA permissions to the DB it is reading from.

When I run the report locally or remotely as myself then I am able to run it, however whenever a member of the domain group tries to run it they get the below error message:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
> (rsProcessingAborted)
>
> The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\user' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Comment: Make sure that they/you have access to the `Data Sets` as well if you have any that are shared.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was so frustrating.  There was one data set that was not inheriting.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem myself and finally figured it out by looking at the `ExecutionLog` views in the SSRS DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Kidiskidvogingogin.  One data set was not inheriting permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the problem above got resolved, I am adding my answer just in case someone else would come across this issue in the future.

Had the same error message, but after many trials of playing with SQL securities, it appeared as if the SSRS folders didn't have the security level required. Added an Admin security level, and the problem was resolved.